# Use a remotely rendered page instead of /public/index.html

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app

I wonder if its possible to insteady relying on the source code of the file stored in `/public/index.html` one can use a remotely generated page to be used as the template for the dev server of create-react-app.

The point is that I'd like to take a page that contains data that is generated by the server and have my react app running in there for development purpose.

As far as I understand, the webpack dev server loads the file from the HDD upon request, modifies the content and delivers it to the browser. So technically it shouldnt be a problem to retrieve the source from a remote URL instead of the local hard drive, right?

Comment: I don't think webpack supports that out of the box, but it shouldn't be hard adding it to the build process. whenever you do npm start, fetch a file (curl) from the remote server, place it some where and then point webpack's config to that file as an entry point.

Comment: Thats an interesting idea, altough it wouldn't be live. I think I'd add a new scripts definition to the package.json so I can run `npm run refresh` or something like that and a script downloads the new source code and stores it in the index.html - this way I would not need to touch the webpack config and also dont need to eject the config of create-react-app. Hmmm...

Comment: you don't have to touch the webpack config, if it points to a certain index.html, simply override that index.html. it really depends how frequently you think this remove "index" is going to change. if it changes every 3 minutes, I'd add a tiny express service that polls and fetches this file, if it changes every day, i wouldn't even bother and simply fetch it every time i'd do "npm start" - this is for development purposes anyway.